# How to setup instances in a private subnet of an AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-vpc

I've been learning about Amazon AWS EC2/VPCs and after multiple videos and articles I've got a VPC up an running with private/public subnets, however, I find myself confused on one key point... how do I connect to new instances deployed in a private subnet, in order to set them up? If I deploy it to the private subnet straight away, I cannot connect to it and setup the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways this can be achieved. A lot of people use a [bastion host](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html). This provides an instance you can SSH or RDP in to then SSH or RDP to your target instance in a private subnet from there. You could also set up a [VPN server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html). This is going to be highly dependent on what type of setup works best for you.

Comment: Setting up a VPN is exactly what I need to do. Thanks